# Ansible target specific host (not delegate_to)

Tags: ansible

There are 3 hosts in my play.

[machines]

- MachineA
- MachineB
- MachineC

MongoDB runs on these servers. And one of these servers can be a MasterDB of Mongo.

So, each of these machines can be a 'Master'. This is determined by setting the fact if the machine is master, in this example only MachineA is targeted:

```
- name: check if master
  shell: 'shell command to check if master'
  set_fact: MasterHost="machineA"
  when: 'shell command to check if master'.stdout == "true"
```

This is also done for MachineB and MachineC.

Mission to achieve: To run commands only on on the Master machine, which has the fact "MasterHost".
I tried the delegate_to module, but delegate_to also uses the two other machines:

```
 - name: some task
   copy: src=/tmp/test.txt dest=/tmp/test.txt
   delegate_to: "{{ MasterHost }}"
```

I want to target the master it in my playbook and run only commands on the master, not in the shell via the --limit option.

Comment: `shell` and `set_fact` are modules, thus your first task contains a syntax error. Your second task purpose is totally unclear. It seems like you need no more than `when: master.stdout == "true"`, but unless you specify what you want, it's a guessing game.

Comment: It was a basic example, syntax errors aside.

I want to execute commands on the MasterHost, and exclude the other hosts in the play.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the command run to check whether the host is the master or not is not costly, you can go without setting a specific fact:

```
- name: check if master
  shell: 'shell command to check if master'
  register: master_check

- name: some task
  copy: src=/tmp/test.txt dest=/tmp/test.txt
  when: master_check.stdout == "true"
```

Run the play on all hosts and only the one that is the master will run `some task`.

Comment: Thanks for an answer.

Comment: ... Still getting used to stackoverflow and how to comment correctly, or even edit.
Anyhow, what also worked for me was to use the `code`run_once: true

Comment: @Kevin `run_once` with `delegate_to` is the wrong way to go. Use @demienfrancois's advice.

Comment: Allright. Can you enlighten why @demienfrancois's is better?

Comment: @Kevin `delegate_to` is used to execute tasks on another host. So at first, you ask Ansible to delegate three tasks to one host, then you limit execution to only one task, also doing some obscure set_fact loop. Why not just run the task on master host and skip them on slaves?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, this was my answer. Sorry for the first post, still learning how to make a good post. Hihi

```
  - name: Check which host is master
    shell: mongo --quiet --eval 'db.isMaster().ismaster'
    register: mongoMaster

  - name: Set fact for mongoMasterr
    set_fact: MongoMasterHost="{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ groups['HOSTS'] }}"
    when: mongoMaster.stdout == "true"

  - name: Copy local backup.tgz to master /var/lib/mongodb/backup
    copy: src=/tmp/backup.tgz dest=/var/lib/backup/backup.tgz
    when: mongoMaster.stdout == "true"
```

Thanks for helping and pointing me toward the right direction.